# Use a XPath to CreateElement

Tags: xpath, vb6, msxml

What I'm looking for is a simple method of turning a XPath into a CreateElement. (My background is C# but this project is for VB6) As an example from my knowlege, if you create a directory with .NET much deeper than just one below an existing directory it will create all the directories all the way down to the one you asked for.

For example's sake, let's have this as a query: `/rootnode/booklets/booklet[@dds="100"]`

Comment: There is no direct conversion, you'll need to parse it and create nodes as required. You'll need to decide what you do about mutiple `booklets` nodes or whether to create a `booklet` node or edit an existing one.

Comment: I've decided writing a parser is too much hassle, but I've managed to deal with nodes in the way I should be dealing with them.